# Move AdView to bottom, Cocos2dx Activity

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-x

Help me please to move ads to bottom of the screen

```
Cocos2dxActivity.this.adView = new AdView(Cocos2dxActivity.this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, mediationId());

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams ad_layout_params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                        


                    Cocos2dxActivity.this.adView.setLayoutParams(ad_layout_params);

                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note : this is in regard to cocos2d-x 3.1.1, though earlier versions should be similar in regard to this.

Cocos2dxActivity uses a `FrameLayout` as its top most layout. In order to achieve what you want, this has be changed to a `RelativeLayout` - in Cocos2dxActivity class, there is an `init()` method which you should edit. There is also a class variable called `mFrameLayout` - just change its type to `RelativeLayout` and name accordingly, and your IDE should tell you where else to change.

As to the banner itself you should give it this layout parameters when adding it to the `RelativeLayout` :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
relParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
relParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```